# My new DNS change works from America but not Sweden

Tags: dns, dns-servers

Several hours ago, I changed nameserver and DNS info on one of my domains at my domainregistar. When I accessed the domain from my home computers and when my friends accessed the domain, they get to the old IP address hosting the dead site (We all live in Sweden).

When I access the website from my mobile phone or through google.com/translate or North American proxies, the website is shown like it should.

Why is this happening? Does it take time for change to take effect for different locations/countries? I find it very strange and would like to start using my site now.

Do you think it will change or could I have been doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will change for sure -- it just can take up to 48 hours for changes to propagate (you have to check TTL (time to live) value for your DNS records).

Most likely you (your computer) still see the old cached details. When cache will expire you will get proper up-to-date details.

When you accessing it via mobile device/another country, these details were not cached there at all (for example, no-one was accessing that site) and they already see fresh details.

You are in Sweden  -- I would say by the morning everything should be fine. 48 hours is the max that not used that often -- usually such delay is no more than 12 hours (depends on registrar/where you host your DNS).

Answer (score 2):

DNS can take 24 hours or more due to caching by ISPs. So a few hours is too soon to say there is a problem. By this time time, or more likely sooner, it will work for you as the cache that if affecting you will have expired and a fresh DNS lookup will be performed.